# ошибка при установке gem pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Сразу скажу, что `libpq-dev`(`libpq-fe.h`) у меня установлен.

```
   Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_config
sh: 1: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_config: not found
sh: 1: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_config: not found
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.0
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /home/mikeoil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@qna/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/mikeoil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@qna/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43902/discussion-on-question-by-chumak----gem-pg).

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема связана с неверным путем до `pg_config` в бандлере. Решается так:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config
```

При установке пакетов postgresql в ubuntu по инструкции ниже - pg_config будет находиться именно в этой папке.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-server-dev-9.5
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config
```

Вы также можете узнать путь до своего `pg_config` командой:

```
which pg_config
```

Содержимое моего `pg_config`, для сверки:

```
set -e
PGBINROOT="/usr/lib/postgresql/"
#redhat# PGBINROOT="/usr/pgsql-"
LATEST_SERVER_DEV=`ls $PGBINROOT*/bin/pg_config 2>/dev/null|tail -n1`

if [ -n "$LATEST_SERVER_DEV" ]; then
    exec "$LATEST_SERVER_DEV" "$@"
else
    if [ -x /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev "$@"
    else
    echo "You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application." >&2
    exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Беда в том, что у автора висят какие-то кривые настройки сборки расширения `pg` в Bundler'е, и он не может понять, где именно: я предполагаю, что в репозитории. Ваш шаблонный код для неуказанного дистрибутива и проекта без локальных настроек ничем ему не поможет.

Comment: Уточнил дистрибутив - ubuntu, и указал содержимое своего `pg_config`.

Comment: Это ничего не сделает с кривыми настройками в Bundler, например. Посмотрите в чат под вопросом, там много дополнительной информации.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку заглянуть в чат, понял суть проблемы. Ответ написал здесь, в чате пока писать не могу (не хватает репутации).

Comment: Окей, теперь ответ имеет отношение к проблеме. Осталось понять, откуда у него такие настройки взялись и как исключить повторение ситуации.